# OnClick on .Master page not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page with name 'principal.Master'. And a form created using the master - 'index.aspx'

I have added the following to 'principal.Master'

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myid" runat="server" OnClick="LogOut" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" >Sign Out </asp:LinkButton>
```

But when the link is clicked on 'index.aspx', the function LogOut in 'principal.Master.cs' is not triggered.

Why is this happening? What could be the alternate approach?

Comment: You can do that in `Master Page.`

Comment: Can you check if you have javascript errors?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not putting the function in the master page as well? Is the function likely to differ between pages?

Comment: show us the code for Logout method from code behind. Does it look like like `protected void LogOut(object sender, EventArgs e) {...`

Answer (score -1):

Use an  ASP button instead and check where have you placed the button.

`<asp:Button runat="server" onclick="Logout" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-flat" id="btnLogout" />`

Comment: Button would distort the current layout. That's why a button was not attempted.

Comment: where have you place the logout function ?

Comment: in 'principal.Master.cs'

Comment: did you debug to see if the code in the cs file is triggered or not ?